# Create a python object that can be accessed with square brackets

Tags: python

I would like to create a new class that acts as a special type of container for objects, and can be accessed using square brackets.

For example, suppose I have a class called `ListWrapper`. Suppose `obj` is a `ListWrapper`. When I say `obj[0]`, I expect the method `obj.access()` to be called with 0 as an argument. Then, I can return whatever I want. Is this possible?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You want to define the special [`__getitem__`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method.

```
class Test(object):     
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        return str(arg)*3

test = Test()

print test[0]
print test['kitten']
```

**Result:**

```
000
kittenkittenkitten
```

Comment: Excellent answer:  on-point, includes a doc link and simple worked-out example.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that there was some method that I needed to define to get at this functionality, I just wasn't sure what the name of that method was.

Comment: Ummmm ... shouldn't "simple worked-out example" include `return some_expression`?

Comment: @JohnMachin: Something more like that?

Answer (score 11):

Python's standard objects have a series of methods named `__something__` which are mostly used to allow you to create objects that hook into an API in the language. For instance `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` are methods that are called for getting or setting values with `[]` notation.  There is an example of how to create something that looks like a subclass of the Python dictionary here: https://github.com/wavetossed/mcdict

Note that it does not actually subclass dictionary and also, it has an `update` method. Both of these are necessary if you want your class to properly masquerade as a Python dictionary.