# How do you do two dimensional (x,y) indexing in Python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, indexing

Generally if you have a two dimensional data structure, it's a combination of two containers - a list of lists, or a dictionary of dictionaries. What if you want to make a single collection but work it in two dimensions?

Instead of:

```
collection[y][x]
```

do:

```
collection[x,y]
```

I know it's possible, because the [`PIL` `Image.load` function](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) returns an object that works this way.

Answer (score 7):

The key is to understand how Python does indexing - it calls the `__getitem__` method of an object when you try to index it with square brackets `[]`. Thanks to this answer for pointing me in the right direction: [Create a python object that can be accessed with square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942669/create-a-python-object-that-can-be-accessed-with-square-brackets)

When you use a pair of indexes in the square brackets, the `__getitem__` method is called with a tuple for the `key` parameter.

Here's a simple demo class that simply returns an integer index into a one dimension list when given a two dimension index.

```
class xy(object):

    def __init__(self, width):
        self._width = width

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return key[1] * self._width + key[0]

>>> test = xy(100)
>>> test[1, 2]
201
>>> test[22, 33]
3322
```

There's also a companion `__setitem__` method that is used when assigning to an index in square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays.

If you have an ordinary Python array, you can turn it into a numpy array and access its elements like you described:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
A = numpy.array(a)
print A[1,1]
```

will print:

```
5
```

Another example:

```
A = numpy.zeros((3, 3))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        A[i,j] = i*j
print A
```

will give you:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 0.  2.  4.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this recipe at the python mailing list](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/dev/767627).  With it you can access the elements of a container using an iterator of indexes.  If you need to use `container[index_1, index_2]` notation, this can be adapted easily using the methods outlined by Mark's post.

```
>>> from operator import getitem
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> l = [1,[2,[3,4]]]
>>> print(reduce(getitem, [1,1,1], l))
 4
```

Here is a different approach suggested on the python mailing list that I adapted to `container[index_1, index_2]` notation.

```
class FlatIndex(object):
  def __init__(self, l):
    self.l = l
  def __getitem__(self, key):
    def nested(l, indexes):
      if len(indexes) == 1:
        return l[indexes[0]]
      else:
        return nested(l[indexes[0]], indexes[1:])
    return nested(self.l, key)

>>> l = [1,[2,[3,4,[5,6]]]] 
>>> a = FlatIndex(l)
>>> print(a[1,1,2,1])
 6
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is relevant to the question.

Comment: I related the question to accessing an element from the container by using an iterable of indexes.  The notation is a bit ugly though.  I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve but your post has been very insightful.