# How to implement a method in a class that uses square brackets in Python (like loc in pandas DataFrame)?

Tags: python

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7942685/10403856) explains clearly and concisely how you can use the `__getitem__` method within a class to implement an evaluation of `self[key]`. I would like to know how one would create a *method* within a class that works with brackets like `loc` and `iloc` in the pandas `DataFrame` class.

The indexer methods in Pandas seem to be [defined as classes themselves](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py). However looking at the [`DataFrame`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py) class it is not clear to me how these get called. So if I have my own class and I want to create a method that works with brackets, how would I implement that?

Based on [user803422](https://stackoverflow.com/users/803422/user803422) suggestions I have set up the following simple code which seems to be working:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        return self.a[-value]

class A:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        return self.lst[value]
    b = B(lst)

x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
​
a = A(x)
print(a[2])
print(a.b[2])
```

This returns:

```
>>> c
>>> f
```

Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Please give an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: I know how to implement `__getitem__` for a class. But now I want to add a second method for getting items from a class that also uses brackets. Thus I would like to add a second indexer to a class, e.g. similar to how pandas gives users the additional possibility to use `loc` to get items from a DataFrame. How would you go about setting this up? Create a second class with `__getitem__`? But how is this class then called in the first class? How do you connect them? Hopefully this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
class A:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print("__getitem__: %s, value=%s" % (type(key), str(key)))

a=A()
a[2]
a[2,5]
a['a':'f']
a['a':'f', 56]
```

The output is:

```
__getitem__: <type 'int'>, value=2
__getitem__: <type 'tuple'>, value=(2, 5)
__getitem__: <type 'slice'>, value=slice('a', 'f', None)
__getitem__: <type 'tuple'>, value=(slice('a', 'f', None), 56)
```

EDIT (after clarification of the original question):

You must move the line `b = B(lst)` as follows:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
        self.b = B(lst)
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        return self.lst[value]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How could I add an additional indexer to `Class A` such that after instantiating `a = A()` I could access it like this: `a.b[2]`? I want to add a second way of indexing `Class A`. The implementation of `__getitem__` under `b` would be different from the one in `a`.

Comment: You should add a class `B` with a `__getitem__`, and do `a.b = B()`.

Comment: Ok, I think I am starting to understand now. I have edited my post with an attempt to implement your suggestion. Can you tell me if it is correct? You may also submit your own answer or edit your own post so that I can mark it as solved. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with user803422 answer, but loc in pandas DataFrames is implemented as a property (see [loc documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc)), more or less like so:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.lst = lst
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        return self.lst[value]
    @property
    def b(self):
        return B(self)

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __getitem__(self, value):
        return self.a[-value]
```

PS:

As Icvriend points out in the comments, in my example a new indexer object B is created every time that the b method is called. Whereas, in user803422 code the index is generated at the beginning. This can be troublesome if the 1st attribute is changed after instancing. See the two examples below.

```
>>> # edd313
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> a = A(x)
>>> a.lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(a.b[2])
2
```

```
>>> # user803422
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> a = A(x)
>>> a.lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print(a.b[2])
f
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks like the difference is that in the first case the second indexer class gets initialized when the main class is initialized. In the second case the indexer class gets initialized each time the property is accessed.

In my initial example the indexer class got passed a reference to the data (`list`). But of course in that scenario it is also possible for the main class to pass `self` to the indexer class.

Comment: Good point, I updated my answer to discuss further